# How to lazy-set Mongoid association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two models that are associated by a `has_one` relationship.  We also have a callback that initializes the association.  The classes look (roughly) like this:

```
class User
  has_one :relevance, class_name: 'User::Relevance', inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :initialize_relevance

  def initialize_relevance
    self[:relevance] = User::Relevance.new
  end

  # other garbage that *should* be irrelevant
end

class User::Relevance
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :relevance, index: true

  # more other garbage that *should* be irrelevant
end
```

Sometimes the relevance association gets into a wonked state where it is nil.  When this happens, we want to re-initialize the relationship when it is called and return it instead of nil.  So in the class `User`, we would have this:

```
def relevance
  self[:relevance] = User::Relevance.new if self[:relevance].nil?

  self[:relevance]
end
```

Except this doesn't work and `nil` is still returned.  I've also tried the same with `update_attribute(User::Relevance.new)` and `self.create_relevance` but `nil` seems to always be returned.  Not really sure where to go from here and would love any ideas.  I can also provide more code or examples if it would be helpful.

*Additional Details*:

- We're using mongoid for our database.
- We don't have any other callbacks that would affect `relevance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid supports autobuilding one-to-one relations. This should help (no hooks or getter overrides needed).

```
has_one :relevance, 
        class_name: 'User::Relevance', 
        inverse_of: :user, 
        dependent: :destroy, 
        autobuild: true
```

As the option name hints, `relevance` will spring to life upon access (if it was nil before access).

Also, you are aware that this way relevance is not persisted, right?

```
  after_create :initialize_relevance

  def initialize_relevance
    self[:relevance] = User::Relevance.new
  end
```

So no wonder it returns `nil` later on.

Comment: This works perfectly, I wasn't aware of the `autobuild` param.  We actually do the callback a bit differently, but you're completely right, I broke it when shortening things.  Thanks though, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the association in the callback, you may try to build `relevance` in the getter method:

```
class User
  def relevance
    self[:relevance] || User::Relevance.new
  end
end
```

This pattern is nicely described here: http://blog.arkency.com/2016/07/always-present-association/

Comment: So I actually tried this and got `NoMethodError: undefined method `relevance' for #<User:0x007fe3f42e14d8>`.  It looks like the super call isn't hitting my relevance association for some reason...

Comment: @RobertIngrum: yeah, because there is no super for this method (with mongoid)

Comment: I've changed to `self[:relevance]`, try now

Comment: Now this is what he tried _before_ asking the question.

Comment: The difference is that you don't build `relevance` after create but when is needed (and then you can persist it). Yet I think that Sergio's answer my solve you problem

Comment: @mrzasa: it's in the second part of the question.